# How to pass a value to a stored view in mysql from php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to have a variable in the where clause of a view in mysql, and then pass a value to that variable via mysqli in php?

I would prefer to keep as much sql in the db as possible and not have huge amounts of concatenated strings in the php code for the sql.

The problem is a lot of my views will iterate over the 12 months, so I can either create a lot of groups of 12 month views in each group or I can have one view for each view type I select and only pass the number of the month to the view as a variable (if possible)

Comment: What you want is probably a stored procedure or function, not a view.

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible.  Use a procedure as @JoachimIsaksson says.

Comment: If it were possible, you would just set the variable before using the view, e.g. `set @var = 3; select * from yourview;`

Comment: "*not have huge amounts of concatenated strings in the php code*" - if you're parameterising your SQL (as you should be), you should rarely have to concatenate anything...